# Object error when calling application

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to open an excel document when a user clicks a button. There are multiple buttons that open the same document but I want it to change the worksheet if the document is already opened and not another instance of the document

```
Public objExcel As Object

Sub Main()
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End Sub

Public Sub QE1_Click()
    Call Main
    If objExcel Is Nothing Then
        objExcel.Visible = True
        objExcel.Workbooks.Open "H:\My Documents\Flowchart to Word\Quality and Environmental management system flowchart.xlsm"
        objExcel.Worksheets("Project enquiry").Activate
    Else
        objExcel.Worksheets("Project enquiry").Activate
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub QE2_Click()
    Call Main
    If objExcel Is Nothing Then
        objExcel.Visible = True
        objExcel.Workbooks.Open "H:\My Documents\Flowchart to Word\Quality and Environmental management system flowchart.xlsm"
        objExcel.Worksheets("Order and project release").Activate
    Else
        objExcel.Worksheets("Order and project release").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Running the code gives me the error: `Application-defined or object-defined error`

Can anyone point out what's causing the error?

Comment: At which line is the error?

Comment: `If objExcel Is Nothing Then objExcel.Visible = True ...` will never work... you will never be able to access a property of a Nothing...

Answer (score 0):

This code here:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Is creating a new Excel Application. Then this one here:

`objExcel.Worksheets("Project enquiry").Activate`

already assumes that the new application is having a worksheet called `Project enquiry`, which cannot be true. Thus, you are getting the 1004 error. Refine your business logic and it should work.

---

In general, try to delete this condition `If objExcel Is Nothing Then` because `objExcel` will never be `Nothing`, you are calling `Main` which assigns object to it. Then the code may work.

Answer (score 0):

A little upgardes to get your code to work more efficiently:

```
Option Explicit

Public objExcel As Object

Sub Main()

    ' don't need to open another instance of Excel, can use the same instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") ' check if there is an open instance of Excel running
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objExcel Is Nothing Then 
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

End Sub

'==================================================================

Public Sub QE1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If objExcel Is Nothing Then
        Main ' call sub that initializes an Excel application object            
    End If

    objExcel.Visible = True
    Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("H:\My Documents\Flowchart to Word\Quality and Environmental management system flowchart.xlsm")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Project enquiry")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If sht Is Nothing Then ' sheet doesn't exist >> raise an error
        MsgBox "Workbook doesn't have a sheet named 'Project enquiry'", vbCritical, "Sheet critical error"
    Else ' sheet object created successfully
        sht.Activate  ' <-- NOT SURE why you need to use Activate ?
    End If

End Sub
```

---

**Note**: same modifications should be applied to `Sub QE2_Click()`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I can see how it's a massive improvement. However, I am getting a User-defined type not defined error on 'QE1_Click' Sub then highlights 'Dim wb As Workbook'. Any ideas?

Comment: @S.T no, can't see why you can't declare a new Object, maybe something funny happens to your Excel. Try restarting

Comment: Maybe the code is not inside a Excel project and the Excel library wasn't referenced?

Comment: @ShaiRado my apologies but this code is being compiled from Word

Comment: Any ideas on how to avoid this error from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control an Office application from within a different one - Excel from within Word, for example, you first need to decide whether you want to write your code using Intellisense and what's called "early-binding" or whether you want to use "late-binding", which does not have Intellisense but has the advantage that you don't need to rely on a link to the other (Excel) VBA code library.

In order to use early-binding you must go to Tools/References in the VBA editor and activate the checkbox next to the entry for the other application (Excel). Only then can you use something like `Dim wb As Workbook`.

If you don't want to use early-binding, then you must declare things as `Dim wb as Object`, same as you've done for the Excel.Application.

In order have code decide whether it needs to use an running instance of the other application (Excel) or start a new instance, use the method `GetObject`. This can be used to pick up *any* running instance, or to check for a specific file.

```
Set ojbExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
```

vs

```
Set objExcel = GetObject("H:\My Documents\Flowchart to Word\Quality and Environmental management system flowchart.xlsm")
```

If what you're looking for with `GetObject` isn't currently available, you'll get an error which you can check and subsequently use `CreateObject` in order to start the application.

```
Option Explicit

Public objExcel As Object

Sub Main()

    ''' Try to re-use an existing instance
    ' If that instance does not exist, an error will be generated
    ' So temporarily turn off error messages
    On Error Resume Next
    ' check if there is an open instance of Excel running
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 
    ' Turn error messages back on
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objExcel Is Nothing Then 
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If    
End Sub
```

Note that you should usually *not* turn off error-messaging - you need a really good reason to do so and you should turn it on again as soon as possible.

If all your buttons are essentially the same - in the two procedures you show everything is the same except the `Else` step - then you can cut down on the duplicate code. (That will also make maintenance simpler if you don't have to make changes in *all* the procedures).

Also, since the `Else` action is the same as the last action in the `If` you can simply put that after `End If`.

```
Private Sub ActivateWorksheet(wsName as String)
    If objExcel Is Nothing Then
        objExcel.Visible = True
        objExcel.Workbooks.Open "H:\My Documents\Flowchart to Word\Quality and Environmental management system flowchart.xlsm"
    End If
    objExcel.Worksheets(wsName).Activate
End Sub

Public Sub QE1_Click()
    Call Main
    ActivateWorksheet "Project enquiry"
End Sub


Public Sub QE2_Click()
    Call Main
    ActivateWorksheet "Order and project release"
End Sub
```